# how to update dropdown value dynamically

Tags: angularjs

I have html code like this

```
<select id="userGroups" name="userGroups" ng-model="userGroups" required class="form-control">
    <option value="{{grp.groupId}}" ng-repeat="grp in groups">{{grp.groupName}}</option>
</select>
```

and in my controller I want to set the default value but its not working

```
function CreateUserController($scope, grpList) {
    $scope.groups = grpList.groupList; //it is loading correctly and dropdown is populating correctly
    $scope.userGroups = "2";
}
```

I am trying to set the userGroups value to 2, but its always showing the first option in select

Comment: Did you already try so set userGroups without double quotes? $scope.userGroups = 2;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best bet here is to use ng-options:

```
<select ng-model="userGroups" 
        ng-options="group.groupId as group.groupName for group in groups">
</select>
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/GruffBunny/k2QGS/1/)</kbd>

Comment: for this I need to change my groups structure from array to json object

Comment: The fiddle has groups as an array

Comment: why its generating wrong values? instead of groupId in value its just showing index there, like value=0, value=1 etc

Comment: The fiddle shows that the userGroups property contains the groupId. Where are you seeing the index?

Comment: The value of userGroups is shown in the fiddle after the text 'You have selected group:'